# jQuery hide element when clicking outside of it working as expected, but not really

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have created a multiple select dropdown list which is opened when you click on a div. Then when you click inside the dropdown list it needs to be open to be able to select more than one thing. Then when you click outside of the dropdown it should close.

I got this code which works as expected, given the logs:

```js
$(document).mouseup(function(e){
    if(!e.target.parentNode.id.includes('multipleSelectDropdown')){
        $('*[id*=multipleSelectDropdown]').css('display', 'none');
    console.log("Outside!");
    }
  else{
    console.log("Inside!");
  }
});

function clickedMultiSelectDropdown(optionsWrapperInput){
    var optionsWrapper = document.getElementById(optionsWrapperInput);
    if(optionsWrapper.style.display == 'none'){
        optionsWrapper.style.display = 'block';
    }
    else{
        optionsWrapper.style.display = 'none';
    }
}
```

```css
.multiple-select-wrapper{
  width: 1000px;
  height: 1000px;
}
.multiple-select{
  cursor: pointer;
}
.multiple-select-options-wrapper {
  box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.35) 0px 5px 15px;
}
.own-input-field{
    border: 1px solid rgb(180 180 180);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
  <div class="multiple-select-wrapper">
    <div class="multiple-select">

      <div class="own-input-field" tabindex="0" onclick="clickedMultiSelectDropdown('multipleSelectDropdownSize')">Size...</div>

      <div id="multipleSelectDropdownSize" class="multiple-select-options-wrapper" style="display: none;">
        <div class="multiple-select-options-item">1</div>
        <div class="multiple-select-options-item">2</div>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

If I click on the "Size..." element the box with options opens. When when I click on the box it logs "inside" and it stays open. When I click below or outside of all elements it says "outside" and the box closes.

**Problem**

For some reason though, when I click on the "Size..." div again when the box is open it again logs "outside" as expected, BUT the box doesn't close. Why? This drives me mad...

Comment: Events bubble up through the DOM all the way to the `document` object.

Comment: @Pointy, The logs are showing the correct thing, so why isn't the $('*[id*=multipleSelectDropdown]').css('display', 'none'); firing as in the other cases?

Comment: Also I wouldn't do this with "id" matching; give the parent a class. Also you're already using jQuery, so you can use `$(this).closest("something")` to check target parent information.

Comment: I don't see the thing misbehaving at all in the snippet, except for when it gets an error checking the parent "id" string (because the event has bubbled to an element whose parent has no "id").

Comment: @Pointy, Click on "Size..." 2 times, it should close the box the 2nd time but doesn't. Please read more careful :)

Comment: OK, I'm not posting an answer for a reason: I think the way you're doing this is wrong. Using the element "style" object values as a way to control behavior is fragile. Use classes and corresponding CSS styles. Mixing native DOM lookup APIs with jQuery is also unnecessary. Use jQuery or don't. If you do, you can use jQuery event delegation to make your setup work with as many clickable select dropdowns ont he page as you need, again by using classes and not "id" values.

Comment: @Pointy, It should close the box but it doesn't, I don't get why. But if you have a better solution that also works for more than box (which mine does too) then please post it.

Comment: The "mouseup" event is fired before the "click" event. Your "mouseup" handler hides the select when the event bubbles up to outside the container. Then the "click" event fires and shows it again.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is confusing. The use of 2 handlers creates a race condition, where `mouseup` wins (as @Pointy noted).

Here is a plain js solution using [event delegation](https://javascript.info/event-delegation), handling only `click` events and using `classList.toggle` to handle the showing/hiding of the values.

It's up to you to convert that to jquery (if [deemed necessary](https://youmightnotneedjquery.com/)).

```js
document.addEventListener(`click`, handle);

function handle(evt) {
  if (!evt.target.closest(`#multipleSelectDropdownSize`)) {
    return document.querySelector(`#multipleSelectDropdownSize`)
      .classList.toggle(`visible`);
  }
  if (evt.target.classList
    .contains(`multiple-select-options-item`)) {
    return evt.target.classList.toggle(`selected`);
  }
}
```

```css
.multiple-select-wrapper {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}

.multiple-select {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.multiple-select-options-wrapper {
  display: block;
}

#multipleSelectDropdownSize {
  display: none;
}

.visible {
  display: block !important;
}

.selected {
  background-color: blue;
  color: white;
}

.multiple-select-options-wrapper {
  box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.35) 0px 5px 15px;
}

.own-input-field {
  border: 1px solid rgb(180 180 180);
}
```

```html
<div class="multiple-select-wrapper">
  <div class="multiple-select">

    <div class="own-input-field" tabindex="0">Size...</div>

    <div id="multipleSelectDropdownSize" class="multiple-select-options-wrapper">
      <div class="multiple-select-options-item">1</div>
      <div class="multiple-select-options-item">2</div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, this works find for one element. However, I will have many of these on the same page. Do I have to create css for all of these elements?

Comment: *Do I have to create css for all of these elements?* Not necessarily. See edited snippet. I'm not a css guru, maybe there are better (css) solutions (than overriding the display state in a generic `.visible` class).

Answer (score 1):

I got some inspiration from both @KooiInc and @Pointy who nearly solved my issue. For my case below code did what I want. It will open the options when you click "Size...", keep the options open when you click them, and close them if you click anywhere else:

```js
document.addEventListener('mouseup', handleSearchClick);

function handleSearchClick(evt){

    if(evt.target.classList.contains('own-input-field')){
        var optionsWrapper = evt.target.nextElementSibling;
        if(optionsWrapper.style.display == 'none'){
            optionsWrapper.style.display = 'block';
        }
        else{
            optionsWrapper.style.display = 'none';
        }
    }
    else if(!evt.target.classList.contains('multiple-select-options-item')){
        document.querySelectorAll('.multiple-select-options-wrapper').forEach((dropdownItem) => {
            dropdownItem.style.display = 'none';
        });
    }
}
```

```css
.multiple-select-wrapper{
  width: 1000px;
  height: 1000px;
}
.multiple-select{
  cursor: pointer;
}
.multiple-select-options-wrapper {
  box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.35) 0px 5px 15px;
}
.own-input-field{
    border: 1px solid rgb(180 180 180);
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="multiple-select-wrapper">
    <div class="multiple-select">

      <div class="own-input-field" tabindex="0">Size...</div>

      <div id="multipleSelectDropdownSize" class="multiple-select-options-wrapper" style="display: none;">
        <div class="multiple-select-options-item">1</div>
        <div class="multiple-select-options-item">2</div>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Thank you both, couldn't have solved it without you!

Answer (score 0):

Your "mouseup" handler fires for each element in the ancestry chain for the target element. When it bubbles to a point in the DOM where the parent id does not have the content you're matching, it will hide the element.

After that event has been dealt with, the browser fires the "click" event, and your handler for the select element will see that the select dropdown is hidden, and so it will open it back up.

Here's what I would do:

```js
$(document).on("click", ".own-input-field", function(e) {
 e.stopImmediatePropagation();
 $(this).closest(".multiple-select").find(".multiple-select-options-wrapper").show();
});

$(document).on("click", function(e) {
  e.stopImmediatePropagation();
  if ($(e.target).is(".own-input-field"))
    return;
  $(".multiple-select-options-wrapper").hide();
});
```

```css
.multiple-select-wrapper{
  height: 100px;
}
.multiple-select{
  cursor: pointer;
}
.multiple-select-options-wrapper {
  box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.35) 0px 5px 15px;
}
.own-input-field{
    border: 1px solid rgb(180 180 180);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
  <div class="multiple-select-wrapper">
    <div class="multiple-select">

      <div class="own-input-field" tabindex="0">Size...</div>
      
      <div class="multiple-select-options-wrapper" style="display: none">
        <div class="multiple-select-options-item">1</div>
        <div class="multiple-select-options-item">2</div>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
  
  This is other content.
</body>
```

Comment: Thank you, this doesn't keep the box open when you click inside it though.

Comment: Oh; I thought you wanted it to close on the second click. What exactly do you want then? When should it open, and when should it close?

Comment: I wrote it in my question... :) It needs to be open when you click in the box, OTHERWISE it should close.

Comment: @eligolf edited. The point of the answer is to give a simplified implementation. You are of course free to further tailor it to your needs if it is not quite what you want.

Comment: And now we are back to where I started, where if you click "Size..." it doesn't close the box

Comment: "It doesn't keep the box open when you click inside it" ... "it doesn't close the box if you click it" — can you see why this is confusing? What is "the box"?

Comment: Yeh English is not my native language, sorry. The box is what comes up when you click "Size...", the dropdown list with options.

Comment: OK now it it will close the "box" (the options) when you click anywhere *except* the `<input>` element.